# LocalStorage not displaying array of todolist after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-applications, local-storage

I'm currently developing a ToDo List using Angular 8. When I enter in a task for my ToDo list it saves it in the Localstorage but when I refresh my page my tasks are gone but are still stored inside the localstorage of the browser.

How do I keep my tasks from disappearing after refreshing the browser, when they're still saved in LocalStorage?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToDo, IToDo } from './todo.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../localStorageService';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IUser } from '../login/login.component';
import { ToastService } from '../toast/toast.service';


@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'todolist',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})
export class ToDoComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Array<IToDo> = [];
  inputtask = "";
  toDoParams = '';
  localStorageService: LocalStorageService<IToDo>;
  currentUser: IUser;
  modal: any;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.localStorageService = new LocalStorageService('todos');
  }



  private toastService: ToastService;
  async ngOnInit() {
    const currentUser = this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage('user');
    console.log('from todos component', currentUser);
    if (currentUser == null) {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
  }





  // Creating a to do item by clicking on the Enter Button

  addToDo(todo: string) {
    const td = {
      id: 1,
      task: todo,
      editing: false
    }
    if (todo === '') {
      alert('You must enter in a task TO DO!')
    } else {
      this.todos.push(td);
    }
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  delete(index: number) {
    this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("index", index);
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  clear() {
    this.todos = [];
    console.log('index', this.todos)
    this.saveItemsToLocalStorage(this.todos);
  }

  getItemsFromLocalStorage(key: string) {
    const savedToDo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    console.log('from getItemsFromLocalStorage savedItems', savedToDo);
    return this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage(key);
    return savedToDo;
  }


  saveItemsToLocalStorage(todos: Array<IToDo>) {
    todos = this.sortByID(todos);
    return this.localStorageService.saveItemsToLocalStorage(todos);

    const savedToDo = localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    console.log('from saveItemsToLocalStorage savedToDos: ', savedToDo);
    return savedToDo;
  }

  sortByID(todos: Array<IToDo>) {
    todos.sort((prevToDo: IToDo, presToDo: IToDo) => {

      return prevToDo.id > presToDo.id ? 1 : -1;
    });
    console.log('the sorted ToDos', this.todos);
    return this.todos;
  }



  logout() {
    // clear localStorage
    this.localStorageService.clearItemFromLocalStorage();
    // navigate to login page
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  }
}
```

Here is the LocalStorageService file below

```
export class LocalStorageService<T> {
    constructor(private key: string) {

    }

    saveItemsToLocalStorage(todos: Array<T> | T) {
        const savedToDos = localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(todos));
        console.log('from saveItemsToLocalStorage savedToDos: ', savedToDos);
        return savedToDos;
    }
    getItemsFromLocalStorage(key?: string) {
        let savedItems;
        if (key != null) {
            const items = null;
            savedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
            console.log('from getItemFromLocalStorage key: ', key, 'savedItems: ', savedItems);
        } else {
            savedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.key));

        }
        return savedItems;
    }

    clearItemFromLocalStorage(key?: string) {
        if (key != null) {
            const items = null;
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
        } else {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the call to `loadToDos()` happening?

Comment: Could you add the source code of the LocalStorageService? That may give some more insight into the situation.

Comment: Added the LocalStorageService source code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so when the page reloads angular loses context of the view so it has to render it again. You have all the working code here to make it work you just have to change the `ngOnInit` page load event so it reads them again and binds them to the property so angular can show them in the UI. Also bare in mind you call `clearItemFromLocalStorage` on logout so this won't grab them if they logout and then log back in, but i guess that was expected due to the code you have wrote.

The below should slot in and work for you:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    const currentUser = this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage('user');
    console.log('from todos component', currentUser);
    if (currentUser == null) {
      await this.router.navigate(['login']);
    } else {
      // if user is logged in go and find any items from local storage and bind 
      // to the view
      const toDoItems = this.localStorageService.getItemsFromLocalStorage('todos');
      if (toDoItems && Array.isArray(toDoItems)) {
         this.todos = toDoItems;
      }
    }
  }
```